# Why the space after the table, and how to remove it?

Tags: css, css-tables

HTML:

```html
<span id="a">
  <span id="b">
    <span id="c">
      Text
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```css
#a { display: block;        border: 2px solid #e00; }
#b { display: inline-block; border: 2px solid #0e0; }
#c { display: table;                                }
```

This shows as:

[image: with display: table]

You can view this in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avernet/kn31qb3a/).

Notice how there is no space between the top of the green/inner box and the red/outer box, but there is some space between the bottom of the green/inner and red/outer box. This is caused by the `display: table`. Adding `margin: 0; padding: 0` on all 3 boxes doesn't have an effect. So my questions are:

1. How do you explain this added space? I'm finding this to be somewhat unusual.
2. How can you avoid it, assuming you need to keep the `display` as-is on all 3 elements, you can't change the HTML (can't add or remove elements), but otherwise you can add any CSS you'd like?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I don't think so. Here the problem isn't due to spaces in the HTML. Edit the HTML in the jsFiddle to read `<span id="a"><span id="b"><span id="c">Text</span></span></span>`, and it will be rendered in the same way.

Comment: I know most of the story. The `display:table` masks the baseline of its contained text, so the baseline of the inline-block is its bottom margin edge, which aligns with strut of the line box that its in, and the total line height has to contain the whole of the table plus the descender of the strut. But I can't find why the `display:table` should mask the baseline of its contained text. `display:inline-table` doesn't, and while vertical-align is defined as using the table box (not the table wrapper box) for inline-tables, it's unclear what `display:table` should use.

Comment: @Alohci: It does so because the table box is isolated in the block formatting context that's established by the table wrapper box. I suspect, if the spec hadn't made an exception for `display: inline-table`, then the same behavior would apply to inline tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > How do you explain this added space? I'm finding this to be somewhat unusual.

   As Alohci has explained in the comments, the `display: table` element masks the baseline of its contained text (which itself lives in an anonymous table-cell within the table box).

   The reason `display: table` has this effect is because, as stated in [section 17.4 of the CSS2.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#model), the principal box that's generated, called the *table wrapper box*, establishes a block formatting context. The table box and any caption boxes within this element participate in this block formatting context, completely isolated from the rest of the layout. This means that the text within the `display: table` element participates in an inline formatting context within the table wrapper box (specifically, in the anonymous table-cell mentioned above) and the inline-block element is completely unaware of this text.

   So, as far as the inline-block is concerned, it doesn't contain any in-flow line boxes since the only in-flow box in its own block formatting context is a block-level table, and [section 10.8 of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) says:

   > The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

   And again as Alohci explains, this causes the inline-block to align its bottom edge with the line box it's on (via the [strut](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#strut)). The added space is there to accommodate typographic descenders on the same line box as the inline-block.

   If you change the `display: table` declaration to a float declaration, i.e.:

   ```css
   #a { display: block;        border: 2px solid #e00; }
   #b { display: inline-block; border: 2px solid #0e0; }
   #c { float: left;                                   }
   ```

   You'll get [similar results](https://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/kn31qb3a/14).
2. > How can you avoid it, assuming you need to keep the `display` as-is on all 3 elements, you can't change the HTML (can't add or remove elements), but otherwise you can add any CSS you'd like?

   There are a number of ways. You can either [force the line-height of `#a` to be zero and restore the line-height on `#b`](https://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/kn31qb3a/15):

   ```css
   #a { display: block;        line-height: 0;      border: 2px solid #e00; }
   #b { display: inline-block; line-height: normal; border: 2px solid #0e0; }
   #c { display: table;                                                     }
   ```

   Or you can [set `vertical-align` to any of `top`, `middle` or `bottom` to `#b`](https://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/kn31qb3a/16):

   ```css
   #a {
     display: block;
     border: 2px solid #e00;
   }
   #b {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     border: 2px solid #0e0;
   }
   #c {
     display: table;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In `display:inline-block` you can use `vertical-align` css property to set it vertically.

**CSS**

```
#a {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #e00;
}
#b {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #0e0;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#c {
  display: table;
}
```

Used `vertical-align:middle` in `#b`. This will set it perfectly without any spaces.

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yudi/kn31qb3a/9/

Comment: It works; but why? The *how* only answers half of my question (second point), and I'm very much interested in the *why* (first point) ;).

Comment: because `display:block` property just convert the as block tag and `display:inline-block` varies height from block

Comment: I'm not following you. I don't see why there should be some space below the `inline-block` if that block contains a table.

Answer (score -1):

The space is being added because your using "display: table" as your container tag, its default is inline and is intended to used with text. Your changed it to inline-block but its still assuming text. So its providing for the space needed to account for descenders in the text characters q, y, p, g and j...
change display to block or change your span to a div which be default is set to block.

Comment: If that was the case, then you should have the same space if `#c` was `display: block` or `display: inline-block`? But if you don't use a `display: table` on `#c`, then the space goes away. So it seems to me that your explanation is incorrect, or at least incomplete.

Comment: An inline-block is a block container box and as such it can totally contain a block-level table. Whether the elements are spans or divs is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score -2):

Why not add this:

`#a{ 
    font-size:0; 
}`

Comment: This will also "hide" the text, which is quite a side effect ;).